# Clean up left-over around a RAID5 coming from a QNAP NAS

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, mdadm, raid-5

I just moved a 12TB RAID5 (4 disks of 4TB) from my QNAP NAS into my Linux Server (`/dev/md0`), and I noticed that there are three "left-over" partitions on each disk (`/dev/sd*1`, `/dev/sd*2`, `/dev/sd*4`), including 3 additional RAIDs entirely (`/dev/md4`, `/dev/md9`, `/dev/md13`).

I would like to do the following:

1. Get rid of those 3 useless raids (`/dev/md4`, `/dev/md9`, `/dev/md13`)
2. Get rid of those 12 useless partitions (`/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda4`, `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb4`, `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sdc2`, `/dev/sdc4`, `/dev/sdd1`, `/dev/sdd2`, `/dev/sdd4`)
3. Resize the useful partitions to take the whole disk (`/dev/sda3`, `/dev/sdb3`, `/dev/sdc3`, `/dev/sdd3`)
4. **(If it's good practice)** Correct `/dev/md0` so that instead of targeting partitions (`/dev/sda3`, `/dev/sdb3`, `/dev/sdc3`, `/dev/sdd3`), it targets the full disk (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, `/dev/sdd`)

I'm extremely worried that I will mess it up and lose all my data... How can I proceed to do this safely?

---

Here are the output of some commands:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFRX-68W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 48FF81CA-3ABB-49C7-8488-0932C696B043

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3     2120584 7813019969 7810899386   3.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  7813019976 7814015999     996024 486.3M Microsoft basic data
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D7C976BE-2F37-482C-9F33-0FD44ED41F97

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3     2120584 7813019969 7810899386   3.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  7813019976 7814015999     996024 486.3M Microsoft basic data
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFRX-68W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 38C30A2A-2D9A-4231-95EB-E26DA29C8785

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdc1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc3     2120584 7813019969 7810899386   3.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdc4  7813019976 7814015999     996024 486.3M Microsoft basic data
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EFRX-68N
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DF6B4D11-3250-413A-8E31-330D321D848C

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd3     2120584 7813019969 7810899386   3.6T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd4  7813019976 7814015999     996024 486.3M Microsoft basic data
```

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68W (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  4000GB  3999GB  ext4            primary  msftdata
 4      4000GB  4001GB  510MB   ext3            primary  msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD40EFAX-68J (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  4000GB  3999GB                  primary  msftdata
 4      4000GB  4001GB  510MB   ext3            primary  msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68W (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3         primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB                primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  4000GB  3999GB               primary  msftdata
 4      4000GB  4001GB  510MB   ext3         primary  msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD40EFRX-68N (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  543MB   543MB   ext3            primary  msftdata
 2      543MB   1086MB  543MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary  msftdata
 3      1086MB  4000GB  3999GB  ext4            primary  msftdata
 4      4000GB  4001GB  510MB   ext3            primary  msftdata


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md4: 543MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  543MB  543MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 12.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  12.0TB  12.0TB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md9: 543MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  543MB  543MB  ext3


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md13: 470MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  470MB  470MB  ext3
```

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda                         8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─sda1                      8:1    0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md9                     9:9    0 517.6M  0 raid1 
├─sda2                      8:2    0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md4                     9:4    0 517.7M  0 raid1 
├─sda3                      8:3    0   3.6T  0 part  
│ └─md0                     9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
└─sda4                      8:4    0 486.3M  0 part  
  └─md13                    9:13   0 448.1M  0 raid1 
sdb                         8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─sdb1                      8:17   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md9                     9:9    0 517.6M  0 raid1 
├─sdb2                      8:18   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md4                     9:4    0 517.7M  0 raid1 
├─sdb3                      8:19   0   3.6T  0 part  
│ └─md0                     9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
└─sdb4                      8:20   0 486.3M  0 part  
  └─md13                    9:13   0 448.1M  0 raid1 
sdc                         8:32   0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─sdc1                      8:33   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md9                     9:9    0 517.6M  0 raid1 
├─sdc2                      8:34   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md4                     9:4    0 517.7M  0 raid1 
├─sdc3                      8:35   0   3.6T  0 part  
│ └─md0                     9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
└─sdc4                      8:36   0 486.3M  0 part  
  └─md13                    9:13   0 448.1M  0 raid1 
sdd                         8:48   0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─sdd1                      8:49   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md9                     9:9    0 517.6M  0 raid1 
├─sdd2                      8:50   0 517.7M  0 part  
│ └─md4                     9:4    0 517.7M  0 raid1 
├─sdd3                      8:51   0   3.6T  0 part  
│ └─md0                     9:0    0  10.9T  0 raid5 /mnt/raid
└─sdd4                      8:52   0 486.3M  0 part  
  └─md13                    9:13   0 448.1M  0 raid1
```

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Sat Nov 30 17:49:29 2013
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 11716348608 (10.91 TiB 12.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 3905449536 (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Jan  7 19:34:13 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : 0
              UUID : ee9fbd79:deea02d8:8b716bd2:ec481317
            Events : 106797

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       5       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       2       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       4       8       51        3      active sync   /dev/sdd3
```

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md4
/dev/md4:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Mon Jun  6 18:43:58 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 530128 (517.70 MiB 542.85 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 530128 (517.70 MiB 542.85 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sun Jan  1 13:40:57 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 2

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : 4
              UUID : 88ff890c:38568eb8:3e3e16e4:4b73851e
            Events : 62

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       2       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2

       3       8       34        -      spare   /dev/sdc2
       4       8       50        -      spare   /dev/sdd2
```

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md9
/dev/md9:
           Version : 0.90
     Creation Time : Sat Nov 30 17:33:27 2013
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 530048 (517.63 MiB 542.77 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 530048 (517.63 MiB 542.77 MB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
   Preferred Minor : 9
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jan  7 20:15:27 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              UUID : 24852f71:56985a76:2842e49e:777267ff
            Events : 0.10614

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md13
/dev/md13:
           Version : 0.90
     Creation Time : Sat Nov 30 17:33:35 2013
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 458880 (448.13 MiB 469.89 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 458880 (448.13 MiB 469.89 MB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
   Preferred Minor : 13
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jan  7 20:15:26 2023
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              UUID : a670af11:ad25d8d9:a20e0676:03ceb388
            Events : 0.5048

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       1       8       36        1      active sync   /dev/sdc4
       2       8       52        2      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       3       8       20        3      active sync   /dev/sdb4
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing :

- Plug the old disks on another computer, then booted on a Linux live CD and mounted the RAID.
- Plug the new disks on the server, prepared a new clean RAID. Encrypted with LLVM.
- Using rsync, moved everything through SSH...

It tooks 3-4 days of non-stop copy, which was probably not the most optimal way to copy these files, but in the end I have a new encrypt RAID (former was not encrypted), and a backup as well, in the form of the 4 old disks.